# C++: Preventing multiple functions from being executed at the same time

Tags: c++, mutex

I ask this questions as all the **mutex** documentations I find deal with a single function and I think my case is very common.

My question is whether the following code won't only prevent `func1()` **OR** `func2()` from being executed multiple times in parallel, but whether it would also prevent `func1()` **AND** `func2()` from being executing at the same time?

```
#include <mutex>

std::mutex my_mutex;

void func1() {
    my_mutex.lock();
    // do something ...
    my_mutex.unlock();
}

void func2() {
    my_mutex.lock();
    // do something ...
    my_mutex.unlock();
}
```

As I understand many people usually copy code from Stackoverflow, I am adding another version of my sample code, after adding @Al_Bundy's input - using lock_guard, which is destructed when the function ends and thus makes sure your mutex is released when the function ends and the guard is destructed. It is much safer and better practice, as it releases the mutex in any case the function returns or exits, even when it exits because of an exception.

```
#include <mutex>

std::mutex my_mutex;

void func1() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(my_mutex);
    // do something ...
}

void func2() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(my_mutex);
    // do something ...
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use [std::lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)?

Comment: Seems like a very good input - if I understand correctly, a lock_guard will unlock the mutex when the function ends, even if it ended by throwing some excetion, right? It is much more safer than unlocking manually

Comment: Yes, exactly. I **only** use it.

Comment: Be careful that the mutex variable really is the same. If it is a global variable, it could be defined as static and exist multiple times in different translation units, if it is a member variable, it could exist for different instances, if it is defined inside a or as a template, that can be instantiated multiple times.

Comment: Do func1 and func2 call each other? Even indirectly by calling a third function, which calls the other one? Or by an operating system interrupt? The question is, do we talk about a different thread only entering the other function or even the same thread entering the other function?

Comment: @Sebastian this is an old thread but I think is still highly relevant. Thank you for your insights. I think it was about multiple threads that were calling `func1` and `func2` independently, while both of those functions used a common non-thread-safe resource. They would not call each other. I agree that different use cases will have different solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your functions are locking the same mutex, therefore at most one of them can be executing at any one time.

Mutexes don't care about functions etc. at all. A mutex itself is either locked or unlocked. Any attempt to lock it while it's already locked will block until the mutex becomes unlocked. You're working with one mutex, so as soon as it's locked by any `my_mutex.lock()` anywhere in your code, all further calls to `my_mutex.lock()` will block until `my_mutex.unlock()` is called.

Once that happens, *one* of the threads blocking inside the `lock()` call will unblock, acquire (= lock) the mutex, and proceed. The others will remain blocked.

Comment: @Lucy says that the lock function will return immediately if you call it from the same thread that has already locked it. This is an important property too

Comment: @SomethingSomething But it's not true. "If lock is called by a thread that already owns the mutex, the behavior is undefined: for example, the program *may* deadlock." https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock

Answer (score 4):

yes, as long as the same mutex is locked, it can't be locked from anywhere else until it is unlocked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in most of case this is true. But pay attention that mutexes have a thead owner. 
As long as it is the same thread the lock() will not wait for the mutex to be released.

Comment: What you're saying is contradicted in the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock)