# Prevent simultaneous function run

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2010, c++11, mutex

ALL,

Here is a pseudo-code of what I'm looking for:

```
class A : public Base
{
public:
    virtual int func();
    virtual int other_func();
};

class B : public Base
{
public:
    virtual int func();
    virtual int other_func();
};

class MainFrame
{
public:
    MainFrame();
    Base *CreateObject();
    int StartThread();
    int SomeOtherFunc();
private:
    Base *m_base;
};

MainFrame::MainFrame()
{
    m_base = NULL;
}

Base *MainFrame::CreateObject()
{
    if( <condition1> )
        m_base = new A();
    else
        m_base = new B();
}

int MainFrame::StartThread()
{
    int result;
    while( !TestDestroy() )
    {
        result = m_base->func();
        Sleep( 5000 );
    }
}

int MainFrame::SomeOtherFunc()
{
    m_base->other_func();
}
```

So in a nutshell: I have 2 classes A and B derived from the same Base class. They both have 2 functions redefined from the Base (a lot more actually, but that's irrelevant). Each of those classes is located in its own DLL.

I also have a main GUI application that calls a method of either A or B by some conditions. It is also spawn a thread at some point of time. In the thread the program calls a function of class A/B.

Now what I'd like to do is to prevent an execution of other_func() when  the func() is executing.

I probably should use mutex for that but now the question is - how do I design it? Should I instantiate mutex inside the function itself or on the call inside the MainFrame method? And does the mutex have to be a global variable in this case? Can it be a member of the Base class?

Again, func() call which happens from the secondary thread, should stop the call to any other method of Base until it finishes.

TIA!

This is with C++11/MSVC 2010/gcc5.4.

[EDIT]:

For an example see the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42763649/c-preventing-multiple-functions-from-being-executed-at-the-same-time/42763683) and compare it with the following code:

```
std::mutex my_mutex;
int MainFrame::StartThread()
{
    int result;
    while( !TestDestroy() )
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker( my_mutex );
        result = m_base->func();
        Sleep( 5000 );
    }
}

int MainFrame::SomeOtherFunc()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker( my_mutex );
    m_base->other_func();
}
```

Is there any differences between those 2 solutions? Will they both work for my purposes - run the threading function exclusively, preventing any other A/B functions to execute?

[/EDIT]

Comment: You need to add some kind of synchronization (e.g. a mutex). Either in the thread, or in the functions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, does it matter where do I put it? I.e., inside StartThread()/SomeOtherFunc() or in the function itself? Is there a difference?

Comment: Your threads should use **single mutex object** for being syncrhonized. How this object is defined - globally, as a static member, as member pointers to the same mutex - is fully **up to you**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, is what I described called thread synchronization or function synchronization? Because the fact that one function runs in a thread is not that important - I just need it to run in the thread, in order to not to block the main GUI one and by the logic of application. I could've run it on timer events or by some other means. Also, see the edit I just did on the OP.

Comment: If you use one unique mutex before any call to any A/B function, then only one A/B function can be executing at any given time. Now the concern is that you would need to go find all of these calls to A/B functions and make sure it's preceded by a mutex lock. Mistakes can easily happen and you can forget just one mutex lock and then debugging will be a mess. Maybe instead you can create some object that wraps any call to an A or B function and makes sure to lock the mutex beforehand.

Comment: I think it makes the most sense to put the mutex as a static member of `Base`

Comment: Conceptually, you don't synchronize threads or functions - you synchronize access to shared data. The point of the exercise is to prevent data races. To this end, a mutex is usually located next to the data it's supposed to protect. Then, any piece of code that needs to access the data would acquire the mutex first; this is easiest to achieve by limiting such access to a small number of helper functions.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, so maybe it just easier to have a static flag in the Base class and {re)set it when I am in the func()? The reason being - I don't have a shared resource - just want func() to be executed on its own, when no other functions from A/B is running.

Comment: But why do you want `func` to be executed on its own? What bad things would happen if it isn't?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, the `func()` will not be executed on its own. All I need is to execute it when no other functions from A/B is executed. Is this what you mean by `executed on its own`? The thing is that this function will run some queries which fail if executed as a second transaction.

Comment: Right. So you have shared data - the database - that needs to be protected against concurrent access. Place the mutex near the piece of data that manages connections to that database.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, so like VictorStone said, I can place the mutex as a static member of the Base class and just protect the calls to the A/B functions?

Comment: If the database connections are managed by a static member of `Base` class, then that sounds reasonable.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, thank you, I upvoted the last response.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, unfortunately MSVC 2010 does not support std::mutex. Any idea of what to do?

Comment: One of 1) upgrade to a modern compiler, 2) find a third-party implementaton, e.g. [`boost::mutex`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html), or 3) use [Windows API facilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Sync/using-mutex-objects) directly.